# Java XSLT processors supporting XPath 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xslt-2.0, xslt

What are the currently available XSLT processors supporting XPath 2.0 standard?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## XSLT 2.0 Processors

There are several [XSLT 2.0 processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Processor_implementations) for various languages.

### Java

Written for [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/), or reported to have a Java interface:

- [Saxon 9.x](http://www.sf.net/projects/saxon) by [Michael Kay](http://www.saxonica.com)
- [WebSphere 7 XML Feature Pack](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/12/was7xmlfp) by [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/)
- [AltovaXML2009.exe](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) by [Altova](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html)

### .NET

Written for the [.NET framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework):

- [XQSharp 2.0](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/beta.htm) by Clinical & Biomedical Computing Ltd.

### Eiffel

Written in [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29):

- [Gestalt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gestalt) by [Colin-Paul Adams](http://colina.demon.co.uk/?q=node/20)

### Other

- [SOA Expressway](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-soa-expressway-xslt-20-processor/) by [Intel](http://www.mashery.com/)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, thus far there are no _free_ schema-aware XSLT 2.0 Java implementations?

Comment: @rustyx: Not that I am aware of. SA is a costly to develop feature and it is typically needed only by few (usually corporate) clients. This determines that as a rule SA XSLT processors aren't free. I *think* Altova 2011 is SA, but even if this is true, it isn't developed in Java, AFAIK.

Comment: You can use Saxon HE 
Check it out here
link[http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.7HE]

Comment: @zakaiter, Right. SaxonHE also is a Saxon 9.x processor as specified in this answer. And back in 2011 SaxonHE did not exist. Anyway, the question isn't about schema-aware XSLT processors -- this topic deserves its own question(s) and a separate SO tag.

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle's XDK](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/xml/xdkhome.html) claims to support XSL and XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

[The IBM WebSphere Application Server Feature Pack for XML](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/featurepacks/xml/) also contains a Java-based XSLT 2.0 processor.