# XSL - Using DateTime Functions

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL document which I am in the process of creating but when I try to use the DateTime functions specified here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Such as `dateTime` or `year-from-dateTime` it says that they're unrecognised functions?

Here are the namespaces Im using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xheader="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:xsales="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xheader xsales"
>
```

I'm currently creating the XSL in Visual Studio, if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime if you want to use XSLT and XPath 2.0 features like those functions. Microsoft's XSLT processors (like the various MSXML versions from MSXML 3 to 6 and XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform in .NET) only support XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

`dateTime` and `year-from-dateTime` functions are in XSLT 2.0.
You are using `version="1.0"`

Comment: Ok, I changed it to `2.0` and I still get the same message: `'dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function.`

Comment: Nope? It says the same thing. `year-from-date() is an unknown XSLT function.`

Comment: Changing the version number in your stylesheet to 2.0 doesn't change the Microsoft XSLT processor into an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515979/java-xslt-processors-supporting-xpath-2-0
http://saxon.sourceforge.net/
http://www.altova.com/xslt2-net.html 
think you can get help from above

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using XSLT 1.0, but the date functions are only available directly in XSLT 2.0. Unfortunately it is not really simple to run XSLT 2.0 from VS but See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205268/how-to-use-xslt-2-0-in-visual-studio-2010) for some info on integrating this against VS.

Comment: I tried the examples in the link but I still get the same error.